# The table row cannot be deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I have difficulty deleting the table row. I find that the data variable in the member.js does not show the date that I input that I submitted. Why is that so? Can anyone find a solution why I can't delete the rows that I added.
My App.css

```
import dataMovielist from '../src/data/data.json';
import Members from './Members';
import AddMember from './AddMember';
import {useState} from 'react';

function App() {
  
  const [datalist, setdatalist] = useState(dataMovielist);

  const onSubmitHandler = ((newHobbies)=>{
    setdatalist((oldHobbies)=>[newHobbies,...oldHobbies])
  })  

  return (
    
    <div className="App">
       <AddMember onSubmitHandler = {onSubmitHandler} />
       <Members data={datalist} onSubmitHandler = {onSubmitHandler}/>   
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Member.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import '../src/css/movie.css'
import moviesdata from '../src/data/data.json';

function Members({ data, onSubmitHandler }) {
  
  const [moviesData, setMoviesData] = useState(data);
  
  console.log(moviesData)

  const deleteMoviesHandler = (personIndex) => {
      alert("hi")
      console.log(moviesData)
      moviesData.splice(personIndex, 1);
      setMoviesData([...moviesData]);
  };

  const tableRows = (data) =>
    data.map((info, num) => {
      return (
        <tr key={info.id}  >
          <td>{info.id}</td>
          <td>{info.name}</td>
          <td>
            <img src={info["picture of image"]} alt=""></img>
          </td>
          <td>{info["lead actor"]}</td>
          <td>{info.rating}</td>
          <td><button onClick={()=>deleteMoviesHandler(num)}>Delete</button></td>
        </tr>
      );
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <table className="table table-stripped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Image</th>
            <th>Actors</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableRows(data)}</tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Members;
```

My addMember.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../src/css/addMember.css";

const AddMember = ({onSubmitHandler}) => {
  const [idmovie,setidmovie] = useState("");
  const [nameofmovie, setnameofmovie] = useState("");
  const [moviepic, setmoviepic] = useState("");
  const [leadActor, setleadActor] = useState("");
  const [rating, setRating] = useState("");
  
  function onChangeId(event){
    setidmovie(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeName(event) {
     setnameofmovie(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeImage(event) {
    setmoviepic(event.target.value);
  }

  function onChangeActor(event) {
    setleadActor(event.target.value.split(","));
  }

  function onChangeRating(event) {
    setRating(event.target.value);
  }

  const transferValue = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const val = {
      id : idmovie,
      name: nameofmovie,
      "picture of image": moviepic,
      "lead actor": leadActor,
      rating: rating,
    };
    onSubmitHandler(val);
    clearState();
  };

  const clearState = () => {
    setidmovie("");
    setnameofmovie("");
    setmoviepic("");
    setleadActor("");
    setRating("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="topFormLayerOne">
        <form>
          <div id="secondFormLayerTwo">
            <label id="labelTwo">Please key in the Id</label>
            <input
              id="inputThree"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              onChange={onChangeId}
              placeholder="Please key in the Id"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFour">Movie Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeName}
              id="inputFour"
              type="text"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Movies Names"
              name="moviesName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelFive">Picture of Movies</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeImage}
              id="inputFive"
              type="file"
              maxLength="100"
              placeholder="Name of Images"
              name="imageName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSix">Lead Actor Names</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeActor}
              id="inputSix"
              type="text"
              maxLength="500"
              placeholder="Name of Actor"
              name="actorName"
            ></input>
            <label id="labelSeven">Rating</label>
            <input
              onChange={onChangeRating}
              id="inputSeven"
              type="text"
              maxLength="10"
              placeholder="Rating"
              name="movieRating"
            ></input>
            <button onClick={transferValue} id="submitButton">
              Submit
            </button>
            <button id="removeButton">Remove Movie</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default AddMember;
```

My data.json

```
[{ "id": 1,"name" : "Ticket to Paradise","picture of image":"../images/Ticket_to_Paradise.jpg", "lead actor": ["George Clooney", "Julia Roberts"],"rating":5}]
```

Can you help me solve theis problems?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem

Your `deleteMoviesHandler` deletes items from their local state of `Members` and what is rendered is the parent state.

#### Solution

You don't need to keep another state inside the `Members` component.
Move the `deleteMoviesHandler` to the parent component and pass it down to Members.

```
function App() {
  ...
  ...

  const deleteMoviesHandler = (personIndex) => {
    datalist.splice(personIndex, 1);
    setdatalist([...datalist]);
  };
  ...
  ...
 
     <Members
        ...
        ...
        deleteMoviesHandler={deleteMoviesHandler}
      />
```

Use it from `Members` component.

```
function Members({ data, onSubmitHandler, deleteMoviesHandler }) {...}
```

Working Demo:

[image: Edit elated-moon-y0my02]